# Netbeans 6.7.1 mainPanel resizing problem

Tags: java, netbeans

I've created a small gui app in Netbeans. As I was adding in some buttons and text areas the mainPanel resized itself. Now it is really wide [probably 4x as wide as I want] but when I try to drag the edge in it won't resize back down. If I drag it out, making it bigger, it takes that change. I would just like to return the mainPanel back to a reasonable size. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried to change the min size, max size, and preferred size settings for the mainPanel with no success. I've even tried to change the menuBar & statusPanel settings at the same time as the mainPanel [thinking that one of them was making the others too big] without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I understand your comments about learning how to code. Nice. Thanks, appreciate your deep thought. I work as a software engineer and I'm doing this as a small project on the side for my wife. I just wanted a small easy to use IDE to gen up this app. Please drop the "learn how to do it right" mantra. Some of us have lives outside of work and are sometimes just looking for a quick easy way to knock something out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans does do really stupid things like that sometimes, and I generally get around them using either of these two methods:

1. First thing to try is to change the `layout` used. Try the Grid Bag Layout, or any of the others and see if you get better results.
2. If that doesn't work, then probably the easiest thing to do is to change stuff in the code. You will notice that Netbeans automatically adds a call to `initComponents();` in the constructor (you have to switch to `Code` view from `Design` view). And if you look at `initComponents`, it will have a whole heap of auto-generated code to create the GUI. Do *NOT* edit this, because it's just a matter of time before Netbeans overwrites your changes. What I do is to create a new method `initComponentsFix`, and call that immeidtaely after `initComponents` in the constructor. In `initComponentsFix`, I would add the code to resize the component to the preferred size, and any other things you you want to fix.

BTW I empathise with you - Netbeans' GUI editor is still in need of much work. However, it's code auto-generation is still very useful, so I wouldn't recommend coding the GUI *the good ol' fashioned way*. That's why I'm advocating using it up until you start felling its limitations, after which you "take control".

---

There is also a third way, which I would not recommend, is to edit the file that Netbeans stores the `Design` view in, which is basically shares the same file name as your frame's class' source code, except with a `.form` extension.
This file is XML, and is pretty easy to edit. I don't recommend this because it is sorta going around the back door, but as a last resort, you can still try it.