# Setting maximum width using Matisse GUI builder

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, grouplayout, matisse

I'd like to create a GUI where some of the textfields are resizable horizontaly but maximum width is also specified. For instance the preferred width is 100 pixels, it can be bigger if the window is resized, but the maximum allowed width is 200 pixels. [GroupLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) supports this, we can specify the max size in the [addComponent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.SequentialGroup.html#addComponent%28boolean,%20java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method (alongside with minimum and preferred).

I'm using Netbeans and [Swing GUI Builder (Matisse)](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html). I can set the textfield to be resizable, I can set the preferred size, but I've found no place to set the maximum size (and for the minimum). Here is the layout section of the property sheet:

[alt text http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/3523/netbeanstfproplayout.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/3523/netbeanstfproplayout.png)

Since maximum size cannot be set, Netbeans use `Short.MAX_VALUE` instead, so if a textfield is resizable it has no upper limit. I've also tried to set the `maximumSize` property of the component but it has no effect and will be ignored.

If I manually edit the `.form` file I can change the `max="32767"` part to `max="200"` and Netbeans generate correct code. Is there a way to set it without manually editing the `.form` file?

Comment: I've set the maximum size from the GUI before (5.5, 6.0, 6.1), but I don't have Netbeans on my work machine to verify it's still there. You might try changing the properties listing from groups to alphabetical.

Comment: Probably you're referring to the maximumSize property I've mentioned in the question. That's a different thing.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? If so, what was the solution, and which version of the NetBeans was this?

Comment: No. It's still not working. :(

Comment: Still not working in Netbeans 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the options that are available on the [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) component with regards to sizing of the component. These settings are suggestions (hints) to the [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html). Ultimately, the [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) determines the component size. In the case of Matisse and the .form object, the layout is controlled absolutely by the .form parameters. There is no automated method of manipulating the .form object from the standard API.

There is a tool called [FormGenerator](http://netbeans.org/projects/contrib/downloads/download/FormGenerator_1.zip) which was designed to try to generate .form objects from existing Swing objects. You may be able to use it to manipulate your .form file dyanmically.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding `initComponentsFix()` after auto generated `initComponents()` method. You can then programmatically set max size like this:

```
private void initComponentsFix()
{
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jTabbedPaneTravelForms, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 800, 900) //changed max size
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jTabbedPaneTravelForms, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1228, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}
```

Basically you override the layout that is build in the `initComponents()` method and set max size to wanted width instead of `Short.MAX_VALUE`. This worked for me. The window stopped re-sizing when at max size and also when at min size set in properties.

Even though this question is old I hope it will still help someone. I solved this problem with help of the following answer [Netbeans 6.7.1 mainPanel resizing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810918/netbeans-6-7-1-mainpanel-resizing-problem) .